# shadowbox library doesn't work with durandal

Tags: durandal, shadowbox

I am working with durandal, and I am using shadowbox plugin "http://shadowbox-js.com/" to view image in a popup

to make it work according to shadowbox documention I have to call:
Shadowbox.init();

so I added it in attached event, but it doesn't work 'may be because the images are not loaded yet'

any solution to make it work??

Answer (score 0):

Try using the composition complete lifecycle callback. See here for more information: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html#combined-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Everything works with Durandal.  Durandal has nothing to do with it.  What you should do is download Shadowbox's jQuery adapter.  That approach is more *appropriate* under Durandal.  Take a look at the link [here](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/support.html#adapters).

Once you have the jQuery adapter in place, writing a quick custom Knockout binding is a breeze.  Then, you can call upon Shadowbox declaratively, in your HTML, using the viewModel to configure it.